# SQL handling null values

Tags: sql, null

The issue is i have 3 conditions good bad ugly. My goal is  if one of the following condition is null then replace null to 0 else if all the conditions are null then show it as null

```
case when 'Good' is not  null or 'Bad' is not null or 'Ugly' is not null 
     then coalesce(value,0) 
     else value
end result
```

The problem here is even with the condition it turns all the nulls to 0 which is not what i want.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you use `coalesce` ?

Comment: @LucM ....because he wants to coalesce? What?

Comment: `'Good'`, `'Bad'` and `'Ugly'` won't never be NULL...

Comment: Oh, I see your point. I was assuming it was a typo and those were column names. Perhaps faulty assumption.

Comment: @user2149435 - You need to post a better example and (preferably) the entire query.  Right now it does not make much sense.  What is `value`?  What do you mean by "*condition*"?

Answer (score 0):

Your code says "if one of good, bad, or ugly is not null" but your question says "if one of good, bad, or ugly is null"

If I'm understanding you correctly, just take out the nots.

Edit: I'm also assuming that you don't actually mean to use the literal strings "Good", "Bad" and "Ugly", but that they are meant to represent column names or something.

You should be aware that using these strings means that your code will never enter the "else" condition, as "Good", "Bad" and "Ugly" are not null.

EDIT 2: take your column names (good, bad, ugly) out of quotes so they will actually be evaluated. This is why you're still seeing that error.

Comment: the question is if good is null and bad and ugly for the same product has a value 0-100 then i want the null to be replaced to 0. if all the three are null for the same prod then i want them to be nulls and not 0

Comment: i did try that . but i get the same issue

Comment: sorry, also read the comments: we're all assuming you don't really mean the strings "good", "bad", and "ugly" because those are not null and therefore your condition will never go to the else. So you probably need to fix something there, too. Will edit answer to reflect train of thought.

Comment: It is for the crop condition. I have a particular crop for the state and particular year and week. I want to get a yearly report.

Comment: @user2149435 - Please define `condition` or give a real example.  Your info is still very cryptic.

Comment: It is for the crop condition. I have a particular crop for the state and particular year and week. I want to get a yearly report. Good bad and ugly are the conditions. the value is in %. say for iowa-1995-weekly number i bring the values. sometimes i have null for one condition and values for others. I do bring all the numbers every if there is not data. so that is why i still want those nulls for the report purposes

Comment: this STILL doesn't tell me what a condition is! Is it a COLUMN on a table, or is it something like this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-condition.html ?

Comment: condition,state,year, commodity ,measure are all columns and for iowa year 1995 corn good-5 bad 10 ugly 25

Comment: jesus that was like pulling teeth. Take your column names out of quotes, then.

Comment: That is not the issue . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your current expression says (in pseudocode):

```
IF <something is true> 
   IF value IS NULL
      RETURN 0
    ELSE 
      RETURN value
   ENDIF
ELSE
   RETURN value
ENDIF
```

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you want something like this. If I get more details I will update.

If I were just going off of this comment

> the question is if good is null and bad and ugly for the same product
>   has a value 0-100 then i want the null to be replaced to 0. if all the
>   three are null for the same prod then i want them to be nulls and not
>   0

I would give you something like this

```
case
    when good is not null then good 
    when good is null and coalesce(bad,-1) between (0 and 100) and coalesce( ugly,-1) between (0 and 100) then 0
    else null
end
```

If you were trying to provide all 3 columns (I am assuming you have multiple columns) you might do something like this.

```
select 
    case 
        when good is null and bad is null and ugly is null then null
        when good is null and (bad is not null or ugly is not null) then 0
        else good
    end as 'good column values'
    ,
    case 
        when good is null and bad is null and ugly is null then null
        when bad is null and (good is not null or ugly is not null) then 0
        else bad
    end as 'bad column values'      
    ,
    case 
        when good is null and bad is null and ugly is null then null
        when ugly is null and (good is not null or bad is not null) then 0
        else ugly
    end as 'ugly column values'
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers . case statement(Its  partially answers my issue and rest i fixed it.  Thanks for your time. I appreciate it. :)